# Не распознается команда в cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

Вот что командная строка пишет

> D:\Code_Staff\wxWidgets-3.1.0\build\msw> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++11
>
> *"mingw32-make" не является внутренней или внешней
> командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.*

Comment: Labzov  Очевидно, Windows не знает, в каком директории смотреть эту команду, а там, где он смотрит, ее нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

При установке секцию *Environment Settings* выполняли? Перепроверьте.